# Poor Javascript and JQuery performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing extreme lag issues with my javascript code. Especially parallaxing is very slow. I expect that this results from multiple executions of the functions. Here is my code:

```
function tada() {
  $(".arrow").addClass("tada");
  setTimeout(function () {
      $(".arrow").removeClass("tada");
  }, 1000);
}

var j = 0;

function thumb() {
    if(j < 18) {
      setInterval(function () {
        $('.equip-thumb').eq(j).css('opacity', '1');
        j++;
      }, 100);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    var color = "#1b1f25";
    if ((i%3) === 0) {
      color = "#1b222c";
    }
    if ((i%3) === 1) {
      color = "#171c23";
    }
    if ((i%3) === 2) {
      color = "#2a313b";
    }
    $('.equip-thumb').eq(i).css("background-color", color);
  }
});

var fired = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var wHeight = $(this).height();

  $(".arrow").css({
    'opacity' : 1-wScroll/wHeight/0.5
  });

  $("#splash").css({
    'transform' : 'translate(-'+ wScroll /10 +'% , 0px)',
    'opacity' : 1-wScroll/wHeight/0.5
  });

  if(wScroll > ($('.section-equipment').offset().top - 0.6*wHeight)) {
      if (fired === 0) {
        fired = 1;
        thumb();
      }
    }
});


$(function() {
  setInterval(function () {
    tada();
  }, 4000);

  $('.equip-thumb').on({
    mouseover: function(){
      $(this).children().css('transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).children().css('transform', 'translate(0px, 100%)');
    },
    click: function(){
      $(this).siblings().children().css('transform', 'translate(0px, 100%)');
      $(this).children().css('transform', 'translate(0px, 0px)');
    }
  });

  $('#portfolio-a').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.section-portfolio').offset().top - 65
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#equipment-a').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.section-equipment').offset().top - 65
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#contact-a').click(function (){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.section-contact').offset().top - 65
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

How could I improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contemplate using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for animation, as the browser will invoke your callback before each repaint, thus it's a better guarantee that animations will be in sync with your monitor's refresh rate, Also, some browsers will make optimisations which ultimately result in more performant code.

Aside from the answers surrounding your use of `setInterval`, your scroll event callback could be wrapped in an invocation of `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(function (lastUpdate) {
        var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var wHeight = $(this).height();

       $(".arrow").css({
            'opacity' : 1-wScroll/wHeight/0.5
        });
    });
});
```

The `lastUpdate` parameter is a timestamp representing when queued callbacks begin to fire, so you could even use this to throttle your logic.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot, in chrome at least. I think I need some poyfill for safari support.

Comment: Safari should support it according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe. That said, Chrome supports and optimises everything very well. Going one step beyond my answer, Chrome supports the W3 API known as `requestIdleCallback`, which is tailored to periodic background tasks such as reporting analytics. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/27/using-requestidlecallback?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

The code below will run forever. Because j < 18 initially, it will execute the setInterval function. However, there is nothing that is stopping the function from ending. Therefore, you are executing $('.equip-thumb').eq(j).css('opacity', '1') 10 times a second forever!

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('.equip-thumb').eq(j).css('opacity', '1');
    j++;
  }, 100);
```

In order to fix this, you should create a for loop instead (to keep things simple) and use setTimeout instead of setInterval. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I tried this way before using the setInterval. Therefore,  I declared the thumb function like this: `function thumb(i) {
  $('.equip-thumb').eq(i).css('opacity', '1');
}` and call it in this for loop: `if(wScroll > ($('.section-equipment').offset().top - 0.6*wHeight)) {
      if (fired === 0) {
        fired = 1;
        for(var i; i < 18; i++) {
          setTimeout(thumb(), 100, i);
        }
      }
    }` The problem is that it does not call the thumb() function this way.